# How to pick an image at some index from UIImagePickerController under UITests in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, uitest

Currently I access photo gallery and pick up a photo the following  way:

```
extension XCUIApplication {

    func pickPhotoFromImagePickerAtIndex(index: UInt) {

        tables.buttons["Moments"].tap()
        collectionViews["PhotosGridView"].tapCellAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

**Example of use:**

```
photosCollectionView.tapCellAtIndex(0)
app.pickPhotoFromImagePickerAtIndex(5)
```

This method crashes sometimes. It depends on photos in gallery.

Is there any way to do this in more elegant and effective way?

Answer (score 3):

I assume, that index you need to tap is counted from the bottom of the collection view. If so, then you can redesign your method:

```
func pickPhotoFromImagePickerAtInvertedIndex(index: UInt) {

    tables.buttons["Camera Roll"].tap()
    let collectionView = collectionViews["PhotosGridView"]
    collectionView.cells.elementBoundByIndex(collectionView.cells.count - 1 - index).tap()
}
```