# How to select images for iOS device library using DETOX?

Tags: detox

[How to select images for iOS device library using DETOX ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfd3j.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see this article on how to write a proper question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is something that the Detox are unable to implement. [LeoNatan](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/676#issuecomment-382892271) at Detox explains:

> UIImagePickerController runs in a different process, thus we cannot control it
>
> Your best bet is to mock the image picker API to just return some default image.

A quick search also turned up this post [E2E: Select an image from a UIImagePickerController with Wix Detox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208456/e2e-select-an-image-from-a-uiimagepickercontroller-with-wix-detox), which as some work arounds that may work for iOS 9 and 10, but it is noted that from iOS 11 and onwards the UIImagePickerController is in a separate process and it cannot be accessed. Again mocking the API seems to be the general consensus.