# iOS Automation - Selecting a photo from Camera Roll

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, xctest, xcuitest

I am writing UI automation tests in XCode and need to select a photo from the Camera Roll screen that pops up in my app. I looked online but can't seem to find any information on how to do this. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Checkout this link, it may help... [Pick image from UIImagePickerController-UIAutomation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490728/how-to-use-uiautomation-to-select-image-from-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: Try using the record tool

Answer (score 2):

The code from the other StackOverflow question didn't work so I figured it out myself. Tapping on the photo itself didn't work but tapping on the coordinate location of the photo seems to work fine.

```
let image = Page.app.collectionViews.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0)
let coord:XCUICoordinate = image.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector.init(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0))
coord.tap()
```

Comment: What is the Page object in your answer?

Comment: This worked well!  I required a second tap with a pause in between since I had a lot of photos on the device I was using for testing.

Comment: Maybe he uses the page object pattern?

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 4+ Automation for choosing image

```
//Title For Photos
XCTAssertTrue(XCUIApplication().navigationBars.otherElements["Photos"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
        
//Check if Moments is visible on the view
XCTAssertTrue(XCUIApplication().otherElements.tables.cells["Moments"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
        
//Click on Moments to see the image collection list
XCUIApplication().otherElements.tables.cells["Moments"].tap()
        
//Checking for "Photo, Portrait, August 08, 2012, 11:29 PM" exist
XCTAssertTrue(XCUIApplication().otherElements.collectionViews.cells["Photo, Landscape, August 08, 2012, 8:52 PM"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
        
//Clicking on "Photo, Portrait, August 08, 2012, 11:29 PM"
XCUIApplication().otherElements.collectionViews.cells["Photo, Landscape, August 08, 2012, 8:52 PM"].tap()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And how do you get that for i18n-ized apps?

Comment: @brainray  may be do your localization on setup

override func setUp() {
super.setUp()
continueAfterFailure = false
XCUIApplication().launchArguments += [“-AppleLanguages”, “(fr)”]
XCUIApplication().launchArguments += [“-AppleLocale”, “fr_FR”]
XCUIApplication().launch()
}